# Casting Entity into it's class type on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the Entity object and I want to get the object.
Currently, I'm using

```
PersistenceManager.getObjectById(Object.class, Entity.getId());
```

The problem with this is that it is an extra call to the datastore when all of the properties are already available in the Entity.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the silver bullet I think you were looking for; it requires some grunt work to accomplish.

**DAO code**

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
 .getDatastoreService();
List<Foo> results = new ArrayList<Foo>();

Query query = new Query("Foo");
List<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(query).asList(
  FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

for (Entity entity : entities) {
  results.add(new Foo(entity));
}
```

**class Foo**

```
public Foo(Entity entity) {
  // TODO get properties from entity and populate POJO
  this.bar=entity.getProperty("bar");
  //get the key
  //if the @PrimaryKey is a Long use this
  this.id=entity.getKey().getId();
  //if the @PrimaryKey is a String use this
  this.id=entity.getKey().getName();
}
```

[a way to convert appengine datastore Entity to my object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291028/a-way-to-convert-appengine-datastore-entity-to-my-object/4630126#4630126)

Comment: It's a nasty workaround, but it looks like it might work. Until the world is perfect, I will use it. +1. But what happens when the object contains a list of another POJO? I.e. within Foo there is `List<Bar> bars`